# Why was it necessary to introduce ref/reactive in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, language-design

This question is NOT about "ref vs. reactive", which is what floods the results when I try to search for the info I'm after. This question is about **WHY they were introduced in Vue 3 in comparison to Vue 2.**

I used Vue 2 a lot, where a very basic app was something like this ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/christophfriedrich/pen/BaGzGGE)):

```html
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
  <button @click="changeTitle">Change title</button>
</div>
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      title: "Hello, Vue!"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeTitle() {
      this.title = "asdf";
    }
  }
});
```

I think that's nice and clean and I'm pretty sure that's not only due to me being used to it this way.

In Vue 3, the template stays the same, but the code changes to something like this ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/christophfriedrich/pen/YzRWRMj)):

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue

createApp({
  setup() {
    const title = ref('Hello, Vue!');
    function changeTitle() {
      title.value = "asdf";
    };
    return {
      title, changeTitle
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

*(Note: I'm not sure if this is the right way to organise stuff in Vue 3, as I'm only starting to learn it.)*

To me, the latter code looks a lot uglier: I have to write `ref(...)` around the initial value, which confusingly is a `const`, and I must use `.value` to actually access it (except in the template). As this feels like a step backwards, it raises the question: WHY was this even introduced? I'm sure there are good reasons for it, but couldn't really find them.

Comment: The thing is as you already noticed it is a preference. Whilst vue3 still allows vue2 style configuration without losing any performance. They thought functional programming is the way to go as there is already a general perception of this

Comment: This is not about Vue2 vs Vue3, but about Options API vs Composition API. Composition API allows you to use previously internal mechanisms (like ref and reactive) directly, instead of through a configuration object. This gives you more control, but it needs more knowledge of the system. There is an [official faq](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html) explaining the advantages in detail

Comment: Ref pattern provides a way to pass by reference that JS lacks natively, hence the name. You can pass it anywhere and will be still up-to-date in both directions. Template refs are just one thing it's useful for

Comment: If I was to address the question in the title, In Vue2 reactivity was provided via `data` function (mainly). It was later exposed as `Vue.observable()`. In Vue3 it was renamed `reactive()` to avoid confusion with rxjs's `Observable` and is no longer necessarily coupled to a component. Along with a few more helper functions, (including `ref`) it was moved in `reactivty` module. That's the main advantage: it's decoupled from rendering and component lifecycle. But in the body of the question you're actually asking about why Composition vs Options API. See @Moritz's comment above.

Comment: I'll add that Vue 2 reactivity system had very specific [change detection caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats), which are no longer an issue with the use of `ref` and `reactive`

Comment: For me, the biggest advantage of Composition API is grouping my code into logical concerns. My code looks nicer, more maintainable than ever.

Comment: Well... I can now use reactivity without using vue components.  So perhaps it was introduced for that reason.

Comment: In regards to the ugly refs, you can still use reactive objects instead. But its a fact the granularity of refs offers flexibility that reactive objects do not have.  Even with vue 2, the reactive objects often cannot be split up without losing reactivity.  The vue3 toRef variants solve this.  Vue3 also offers the shallow flavors, that further give the developer options.